# Login User Mapping issue in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

A while back I set up a database under SQL Server 2008 called myDB in Windows XP, then under Logins under the server, I clicked Properties on my computer login name COMP23/Andrew and mapped myDB database to this using dbowner as its rights.

Then I cloned this XP installation as a backup, installed Visa, realising I did not want Vista I re-imaged back my original XP copy onto the same machine. However the DB mapping has got really confused! Basically under the server login COMP23\Andrew, it says its mapped to myDB, but when I click myDB and look at its users its not there. I think its lost its SID mapping because it thinks its a new machine.

Under the server login COMP23\Andrew I can't untick the mapping to myDB as when I do it says "Cannot drop the user dbo". I can't alter the dbo user either - it won't let me. But nor can I make the user appear under myDB users! Which means I can't login through my website settings (asp.net web.config) file! When I login it just says Cannot open database "myDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'COMP23\ASPNET'

Any ideas? How I can remap this properly? I've even tried reinstalling SQL Server 2008 but the computer name is still there mapped to the database.

Answer (score 15):

Because dbo is the owner of the database, its mapping must be changed by changing the owner of the database:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON database::[<yourdb>] TO [sa];
```

Comment: This solution works for me. Thanks Remus! I had this situation: domain\oldusr not working anymore in our company. domain\oldusr mapped as "dbo" (see under user mappings) for several DBs. This was causing problems when I was trying to use the Tasks > "Copy Database" wizard to copy the DB from a machine to another. I was getting this error: Cannot find the principal 'domain\oldusr', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. Running the above query dropped the user mapping (as dbo) from that DB. So in the end I could copy the DB using the Tasks > Copy Database.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't have quote marks surrounding the stored procedure name.  Secondly, it isn't autofix but auto_fix.

Finally, once those corrections are made, you get this error message:

> Msg 15600, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_change_users_login, Line
>   181 An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure
>   'sys.sp_change_users_login'.

when you run this command:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action = 'auto_fix', @LoginName = '<your username>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the SID mapping issue, have you tried using [`sp_change_users_login`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx)?  Use the autofix option to re-map your login to the one in the database.

For your example above you should execute the following while connected to the database

```
EXEC `sp_change_users_login` @Action = 'autofix', @LoginName = 'COMP23\ASPNET'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [Database]
GO

ALTER USER [dbo] WITH NAME=[username]
GO

sp_changedbowner 'sa' 
GO
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.